# Really basic Django E-commerce? Where do I start

Tags: django, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I'm trying to set up a really basic e-commerce site with Django, and am trying to figure out the best place to start. I am relatively comfortable with the framework itself, but have never done any sort of e-commerce development in any language, so I want to learn about some best practices so I don't make any huge or obvious mistakes.

I've looked at Satchmo, and even went as far as installing and playing around with it, but it looks like way more than I want. I basically want to show users a list of things, and let them click a button to buy one. No cart, no shipping, just click a button, connect with Authorize.net (or something similar) to do the transaction, and then display a confirmation page.

Any suggestions or online tutorials people have found helpful? Even perhaps a tutorial in another language. Or maybe a really lightweight Django plugin that doesn't try to do everything like Satchmo? I've been coming up with very little so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I did [some research](http://readncode.com/blog/the-state-of-ecommerce-in-django/) recently that may be of interest. Basically, I think Satchless is the most promising right now.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, but [Lightning Fast Shop](http://www.getlfs.com/start) is a Django-based alternative to Satchmo, which is supposed to be pretty lightweight and so might fit your needs a bit better.